# Selenium WebDrive Java Firefox Headless not working

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Im trying to run Fiorefox headless locally on my Macbook but so far no luck. Im working on Selenium WebDrive Java.

I tried this 2 approach to solve the problem and both of them work just fine except for the headless option that is completely ignored.

```java
package Follo;

public class Class_4 {

    @Test
    public void Firefox1() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/alessandroborini/Dropbox/Firefox Drivers/geckodriver");

        FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
        firefoxBinary.addCommandLineOptions("--headless");
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        options.setBinary(firefoxBinary);

        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void Firefox2() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/alessandroborini/Dropbox/Firefox Drivers/geckodriver");

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        options.setHeadless(true);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver. quit();
    }
}
```

I have a few warning at the beginning of the test but they do not seem connected to my issue from what I see.

Here are the warning in console but no errors:

````
1562862838014   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons
1562862838014   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: telemetry
1562862838015   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/
1562862838015   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*
1562862841133   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 57308
1562862841209   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Jul 11, 2019 5:34:01 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C```

```PASSED: Firefox1
PASSED: Firefox2

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================```
````

Comment: Can you paste error message you are getting after running above tests

Comment: The 2 tests aboe drops no errors they do just work fine is only the headless option that gets ignored all the time. I have tho some warning in console.Updated the main question with the warnings

Answer (score 4):

Instead of adjusting the command line for the binary, explicity set the headless flag directly in the options:

```java
FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary(firefoxBinary);
options.setHeadless(true);  // <-- headless set here
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

**add this line in you code it will be helpful for you**

System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "firefoxLog");
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.OFF);

Comment: Can you explain how this will help?